# Weird situation with Empty String

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have code to parse Date Field only if String is not null or empty  but I get the following Exception

Conversion from string " " to type 'Date' is not valid.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from string " " to type 'Date' is not valid.

Source Error:

```
Line 29:         
Line 30:  If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(last_login)) Then 
Line 31:    If  String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss}", last_login) < Now.AddMinutes(-5) Then
Line 32:      Return "height:100%;width:100% ;background-color:#FF0000;font-weight: bold; color: #000000"
Line 33:    Else
```

Anyone please explain?

Comment: @Richard Cook-  thanks for the reformat.  Less than 750 points before I can do that.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a mess. You're trying to use date formatting symbols on a string, to produce a string, to compare with a date.

Let's try this instead.

```
Dim dLast As DateTime
If ((Not last_login Is Nothing) AndAlso DateTime.TryParse(last_login.Trim(), dLast)) Then
    If (dLast < Now.AddMinutes(-5)) Then
        Return "height:100%;width:100% ;background-color:#FF0000;font-weight: bold; color: #000000"
    End If
End If
```

edit: check for `null` string before access it.

Comment: +1 - This is eliminates a lot of implicit casting (btw only works in VB) which speeds performance, plus it is significantly more bulletproof and less likely to cause a nasty exception farther down the road. Also, the .Trim() isn't needed with the DateTime.TryParse, it does it itself (plus it makes last_login = Nothing safe to run as well, as calling .Trim() on it will except if last_login is Nothing).

Answer (score 6):

`" "` is not the empty string.  (There's a space inside.)  Perhaps you should call `.Trim()`:

```
last_login != null && last_login.Trim().Length > 0
```

Or if you're using .NET 4, `IsNullOrWhitespace` is even better:

```
string.IsNullOrWhitespace(last_login)
```

**Edited**, thanks to @Anthony and @Joel.

Comment: Plus if you're on .NET 4, `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` is also useful.

Comment: null.Trim() doesn't work so good. Perhaps `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(buh) && buh.Trim().Length > 0`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`. I see a space character inside quotes.

Answer (score 1):

.TryParse is fine with string = nothing

```
Dim dLast As DateTime
If DateTime.TryParse(last_login, dLast) Then
    If (dLast < Now.AddMinutes(-5)) Then
        Return "height:100%;width:100% ;background-color:#FF0000;font-weight: bold; color: #000000"
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

" " is a space, which is neither null nor empty.  You can Trim() the string first, and then check for null, Empty, or Length == 0.

Answer (score 0):

It is not null or empty. It is a space. You could try trimming it.